# need to pass a variable value into dictionary as a value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have stored a value into a variable. Below is that-

```
itemID = item['witId'] 
print "new ID is :" +str(itemID)
```

now i want to pass the itemId's value into the following dictionary:

```
data = '{"witIds": ["itemID "], "widgetExpiryDate":"12.06.2015 09:12:00.UTC" , "firstAlertDate":"11.06.2015 04:06:00.UTC","secondAlertDate":"11.06.2015 05:02:00.UTC"   }'
```

This code shows me that `itemID` is not valid.

Comment: that....does not look like a dictionary. That looks like json to me.

Comment: What's in your `itemID`?

Comment: What is the original `item` dictionary? If you try to get a key from a dict that it doesn't have, then print it, it will error. Also, when you set up the new `data` dict you dont need the quotes around the whole thing, and if you want to add the variable `itemID` to it you shouldn't have quotes around it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is what you want:

```py
itemID = item["witId"]
data = {"widgetExpiryDate":"12.06.2015 09:12:00.UTC" , "firstAlertDate":"11.06.2015 04:06:00.UTC","secondAlertDate":"11.06.2015 05:02:00.UTC"}
data["witIds"] = [itemID]
```

If you are trying to convert that JSON to dictionary, you can use `json` module:

```py
import json
data = '{"widgetExpiryDate":"12.06.2015 09:12:00.UTC" , "firstAlertDate":"11.06.2015 04:06:00.UTC","secondAlertDate":"11.06.2015 05:02:00.UTC"   }'
json.loads(data)
```